# Javascript adding/removing values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this JS Code:

```
$("#submit").on('click',function() {
    //work out number of days between the two dates
    var days_between = $("#todate").val() - $("#fromdate").val()

    //do the cost per month times 12 (months)
    var year_cost = $("#cost_per_month").val() * 12

    //do the yearly cost / 365
    var daily_cost = year_cost / 365
    var daily_cost = parseFloat( daily_cost.toFixed(2) )

    //now do the daily cost times cost_per_month
    var total_cost = daily_cost * days_between

    $(".total_days").html(days_between);
    $(".total_cost").html(total_cost);
})
```

I am getting an error saying NaN though.

i am entering the following:

```
#from_date = 2014-08-19
#to_date = 2014-08-31
#cost_per_month = 2.60
```

Comment: Not suprisingly, `"2014-08-19" - "2014-08-31"` is not a number ?

Comment: are IDs 'fromdate' 'todate' or 'from_date' 'to_date'

Comment: It would be useful to know if you're using a datepicker or just typing the dates. If you're using something like jQuery's datepicker it would give you totally different answers.

Answer (score 2):

The way you are calculating number of dayes between the dats is wrong. look into this
[How do I get the number of days between two dates in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542938/how-do-i-get-the-number-of-days-between-two-dates-in-javascript)
This could be helpful!

Answer (score 1):

This Will Work

```
    //work out number of days between the two dates
var oneDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; 
//var date1 = new Date("2014,08,31");
//var date2 = new Date("2014,08,19");

var date1 = new Date("2014-08-31");
var date2 = new Date("2014-08-19");

var Daysd = date1.getDate() - date2.getDate();

    //var days_between = date1 - date2
    var diffDays = Math.round(Math.abs((date1.getTime() - date2.getTime()) / (oneDay)));

    //do the cost per month times 12 (months)
    var year_cost = parseInt(2.60) * 12

alert(Daysd);
alert(year_cost);
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ashuslove/d6f29afv/1/)

Comment: Close, but no cigar, the OP is getting the values as strings from inputs.

Comment: @adeneo, how about now?

Comment: That is closer, and the OP could insert the strings from the values, so I'll give it a +1

Comment: @user3843997, you are wel come to accept the answer. plz do it :) ;)

Answer (score 0):

you can't get total days directly

```
   var tDate = new Date($("#todate").val());
    var fDate = new Date($("#fromdate").val());
    var diff=tDate-fDate;

    This would give you the difference in milliseconds between the two dates.

    var DaysNo= diff / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24;
```

Answer (score -1):

You have not parsed textbox values to int:

```
var days_between = parseInt($("#todate").val()) - parseInt($("#fromdate").val())
```

and

```
var year_cost = parseInt($("#cost_per_month").val()) * 12
```

Comment: That's like writing `parseInt("2014-08-19") - parseInt("2014-08-31")`, I'm not sure you'd get the expected result ?

Comment: Yep parseInt("2014-08-19" ) yields just the first int it finds

Comment: I dont think that they are in date format. OP would have not done the operation of multiplying with integer values.

Comment: You sould use new Date().getTime(string); to get the date parsed in ms